# Google Calendar event time

Tags: google-calendar

How can I set an event at a particular time? When you add an event, it expects a time range, and when you set a task, it doesn't allow you to specify the time by which the task must be completed. How else can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Tasks" that is built into Google Calendar does not allow you to assign a specific time. If you'd like to do this in Google Calendar without using other tools, then you can set up every task as a normal event. Add a tag in the front of the Event title

```
[TODO] Finish writing thing for dude
```

This will help you identify tasks. You can also change the color of the event/task. You can also set up another calendar just to create Task Events, which you can then toggle on and off in the "My calendars" list.

Comment: Could you set a reminder for them at least?

Comment: Yes if you make them all events, but no if you're trying to use default task items.

Comment: Ah, OK. Hope they add that.